# Related to react-native-zoom-us

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zoom-sdk

I was using react-native-zoom-us from past couple of months and it stops working suddenly
then when i was debugging it i saw en error **ZoomUS.initialize requires jwtToken** i was using meeting sdk and client key, secerete key to authenticate and now suddenly it asking to jwt token but zoom deprecated jwt token long time ago what to do now?
[image]